# paypal This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

Here is the code I used

```
 $max_amount = 20;
            //$max_amount = $this->currency->convert($order_info['total'], $this->config->get('config_currency'), 'USD');

            $max_amount = min($max_amount * 1.25, 10000);
            $max_amount = $this->currency->format($max_amount, $this->currency->getCode(), '', false);
            $max_amount = $max_amount*100;
            $data = array(
                'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
                'MAXAMT' => $max_amount,
                            'AMT'    => 1000,
                'RETURNURL' => $this->url->link('payment/pp_express/checkoutReturn', '', 'SSL'),
                'CANCELURL' => $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL'),
                'REQCONFIRMSHIPPING' => 0,
                'NOSHIPPING' => 1,
                'LOCALECODE' => 'EN',
                'LANDINGPAGE' => 'Login',
                'HDRIMG' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->config->get('pp_express_logo'), 790, 90),
                'HDRBORDERCOLOR' => $this->config->get('pp_express_border_colour'),
                'HDRBACKCOLOR' => $this->config->get('pp_express_header_colour'),
                'PAYFLOWCOLOR' => $this->config->get('pp_express_page_colour'),
                'CHANNELTYPE' => 'Merchant',
                'ALLOWNOTE' => $this->config->get('pp_express_allow_note'),
            );

            $data = array_merge($data, $this->model_payment_pp_express->paymentRequestInfo());
            echo '<pre>';
            $result = $this->model_payment_pp_express->call($data);

            print_r($result);
```

The result of print_r($result) is

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-05-26T13:48:19Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => d5ff8073cbde
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 65.2
    [BUILD] => 11110362
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10525
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Data
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Whether I have to round up the values?

Comment: Can you debug your code and find out what is the `$max_amount` value before it is *currency-formatted* and afterwards? Also can you post here what data (request) is sent to PayPal? Are you sure you use the right parameter names for method given?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the AMT parameter included in your request.  As such, it's getting seen as a zero value which PayPal doesn't accept.

You need to add the AMT parameter and pass the current amount of the order at the time the SEC request is made.  Of course, this amount could change between that time and the final DoExpressCheckoutPayment request, but you just need to make sure the final amount is not greater than the MAXAMT you're passing here.

Comment: Check my edited question added AMT and now MAXAMT is 2500 and AMT is 1000

Comment: Something funky must be happening for it not to see the amount, or to see a zero amount.  Can you post a copy of the raw reqeust that's actually getting sent instead of the code generating it?